# helm install qliksense | secrets already exists Ask

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am pretty new to kubernetes. I run a kubernetes cluster on EKS (AWS).

When installing QlikSense on kubernetes I receive the following error.

command:

`helm install -n qliksense qlik/qliksense -f values.yaml`

error:

`Error: release qliksense failed: secrets "qliksense-nats-secret" already exists`

Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Use `kubectl get secrets` and check if You have qliksense-nats-secret there, if yes just delete it and use helm install again.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Kubernetes and helm are you using? The issue happends with the qliksense stable release in Kubernetes >1.15 and helm >=2.15, if you use older versions you should be good, or use the edge release of qliksense. You can read here:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-admin/November2019/Subsystems/DeployAdministerQSE/Content/Sense_DeployAdminister/Common/system-requirements-qseok.htm

Answer (score 0):

The edge release has no issues, try

```
helm repo add qlik-edge https://qlik.bintray.com/edge
helm init
helm repo update
helm install -n qlikinit qlik-edge/qliksense-init
helm install -n qliksense qlik-edge/qliksense -f values.yaml
```